# What kind of things can we be hooked on?

Tags: phrase-usage

> I'm hooked on trees. Especially during the fall when they shed their
> leaves.

Is it natural to say ,I am hooked on something general which is not addictive and is not your own?

Comment: Have you checked a good dictionary? Do you understand what "strongly attracted to something or someone" means? Do you understand what "enjoying something so much that you are unable to stop having it, watching it, doing it, etc" means?

Comment: Please see [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hooked): Devoted to or absorbed in something. *I must admit I am still hooked on the series, the developing characters and their ongoing, individual stories.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hooked" means it is addictive, even if only psychologically.

You can say "I'm hooked on the series, the developing characters and their ongoing, individual stories".  This means that your behaviour is like someone who is addicted. You are saying that you are (to some degree) unable to stop.

If you are "hooked on trees" that means that you are saying that you are not just interested in trees, but that you are obsessive!  You can't stop interacting with trees. You act like you *are* addicted. The grammar is fine, but is this really the meaning that you want to give?

Comment: We can say "hooked", casually, to just mean 'very interested in'. I am hooked on the TV series 'Deutschland 83' at the moment, and will watch all the 27 episodes. I won't be hooked after that, at least not in the same way. I don't think this is 'obsessive', even though Jonas Nay is a very good actor.